# SELECT and JOIN to return only one row for each employee

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I have a user table that stores the employeeId, lastName, firstName, department, hire date and mostRecentLogin.

I have another table that stores the employeeId, emailAddress.

The emailAddress table can have multiple rows for an employee if they have multiple email addresses.

I'm trying to return results that only show one row for each employee. I don't care which email address, just as long as it only picks one.

But all the queries I've tried always return all possible rows.

Here is my most recent attempt:

```
select *
from EmployeeInfo i
left join EmployeeEmail e ON i.employeeId = e.employeeId
where i.hireDate = 2015 
and employeeId IN (
    SELECT MIN(employeeId)
    FROM EmployeeInfo
    GROUP BY employeeId
)
```

But then again, this returns all possible rows.

Is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: You can `LEFT JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 email....) x ON x.employeeId = userTable.employeeId`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a sub-query instead of a join:

```
select *
  , (select top 1 E.EmailAddress from EmplyeeEmail E where E.employeeId = I.employeeId)
from EmployeeInfo I
where I.hireDate = 2015;
```

Note: If you change your mind and decide you do have a preference as to which email address is returned then just add an `order by` to the sub-query - otherwise it is truly unknown which one you will get.

Comment: Well, without an `ORDER BY` to go on, it's rather arbitrary *which* row you'll be getting. If that's ok with you - fine - but typically you want a *specific* row (the first, the last - ordered by whatever it might be) and this only works if you provide an `ORDER BY` clause as well

Comment: @marc_s sure - wouldn't call that dangerous though? OP said "I don't care which email address, just as long as it only picks one." - so I took them at their word :) but yes I would never do that myself.

Comment: Dangerous as in many folks would expect a certain "default" ordering - which just isn't there in any RDBMS I know of. So it might end up returning an unexpected (and potentially "wrong" result) - but you're right, as long as it doesn't matter which row gets returned, then your code is fine

Comment: @marc_s would you ORDER BY E.EmailAddress?  Thanks

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell: order by whatever makes sense for you - e-mail address, first name, last name, shoe size - whatever your system needs ....

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
SELECT *
FROM EmployeeInfo
Left JOIN EmployeeEmail
  ON EmployeeInfo.employeeId = EmployeeEmail.employeeId
WHERE EmployeeInfo.hireDate = '2015'
GROUP BY EmployeeInfo.employeeId;
```

Comment: Thats not going to work on SQL Server as you are attempting to select `*` but only grouping by `employeeId`.

Comment: @DaleK oh, interesting. But I thought that since EmployeeInfo.employee.Id column has duplicate data values we would be able to group here?

Comment: Firstly, I seriously doubt there are duplicate employeeId's in the EmployeeInfo table, the duplicate is in the EmployeeEmail table. Secondly you can only select columns you group by or aggregate by so you would have to change `select *` to `select EmployeeId`